# Is what is inside of an Egg Pre-Determined?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon games, are the contents of eggs pre-determined or randomly created on the spot when they hatch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its determined when they are laid or recieved, which prevents players from resetting the game in order to reroll the attributes of the pokemon. This can be proven by hatching an egg, then restarting the game without saving and hatching it again (which will have the same result)

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but what I was expecting/

Comment: So is it *laid* or *received*? I've seen breeding guides claim both. Smogon's guide even says that Nature/Gender/Ability are set when laid and IVs when received (in earlier gens), so I'm not sure what to believe.

Comment: @geobits there isn't a functional difference between the two, either way by the time you get your hands on it its already set

Comment: @Lawton If it's set only when received, I could save/reset right before I pick it up and save egg "generation" time. That could be useful for parents that don't get along well. If it's set when laid, that won't work.